# Scala code: reverse operation

Tags: scala

I wanted to ensure I understand some scala code correctly. I have a method in a class as:

```
def getNodes(): IndexedSeq[Node] = allNodes
```

Then somewhere this method gets called as:

```
val nodes = graph.getNodes()
```

and then there is a line

```
val orderedNodes = nodes ++ nodes.reverse
```

Does this make another sequence where the original sequence and the reversed get concatenated or is there some other subtlety to it as well?

Comment: I would believe it makes a new sequence with the nodes followed by the nodes in reverse order. I don't know why that would be called `orderedNodes` though. There shouldn't be any subtleties, but we would need to see the full source to be certain and let us know which graph lib this is.

Comment: Thanks for that. The library can be found here: https://github.com/danielkorzekwa/bayes-scala

I am trying to understand the methods behind it. I think orderedNodes sort of indicates the order the nodes will be visited by the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the result is a new IndexedSeq containing items just like you wrote. You're calling methods `++` and `reverse` that are well documented here:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.IndexedSeq

Your code can be written like this:

```
val orderedNodes = nodes.++(nodes.reverse)
```